# Share a text box content from my website directly to Linkedin using Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, share, linkedin-api

I want to share the content from my localhost webpage Textbox directly on my Linkedin page which is already logged in.
Share button from Linkedin is redirecting to the share post page, I wanted that Post Status Textarea to be auto filled with text from my website's textbox content.
I really appreciate your help...

Comment: Have you taken a look at LinkedIns REST API?? It allows you to define things like a title, description etc.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin